# Gap in Lightning Page when Aura Component Doesn't Render

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience

I am writing an Aura Component that only needs to render in certain situations. This can't be done with Component Filtering as it requires some pretty complex background logic. I am achieving this functionality by wrapping my card in an `aura:if` tag. Here is an example that will create the problem.

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForRecordHome">  
    <aura:if isTrue="{!false}">
        <article class="slds-card">
            <div class="slds-card__body slds-card__body_inner">
                <!--Card Body goes here -->
                Test component
            </div>            
        </article>
    </aura:if>
</aura:component>
```

It's worth noting that in the actual component, there is more logic, it's not just `isTrue={!false}`.

If you put that component on a layout, it leaves a gap. The sidebar components are now slightly below the main detail section, even though they normally line up.

[image: There is a small 10px gap where the component should be.]

Is there a way to remove this gap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The margin (bottom) is added by lightning flexi-page. You can use the `aura:html` to inject CSS if you want to remove it but it can break in certain scenarios.

1. Any release where the base component name is changed. Currently it is `flexipage-component2`.
2. If SF tries to enforce CSS encapsulation/namespacing to CSS generated in `aura:html` tag.
3. The CSS would impact all the component instances of same component. You can definitely add conditional logic to prevent that.

*Do change the `TestComp` with the name of your component in line 3*

---

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForRecordHome"> 
    <aura:html tag="style">
        flexipage-component2[data-component-id="TestComp"] { // CHANGE THE COMPONENT ID HERE WIHT YOUR COMPONENT NAME
            margin-bottom: 0 !important;
        }
    </aura:html>
    <aura:if isTrue="{!false}">
        <article class="slds-card">
            <div class="slds-card__body slds-card__body_inner">
                <!--Card Body goes here -->
                Test component
            </div>            
        </article>
    </aura:if>
</aura:component>
```